# Operandos Inválidos

Tags: arduino

Sucede que no me permite guardar el String agregando el valor de la variable sensor de luz **¿Algo estoy haciendo mal?**

```
Por lo que veo es un error de codigo simple....
```

Codigo:

```
    int sensorLuz = analogRead(pinSensorLuz);
    String cadena = ("<font color='red'> <font size=5>" +sensorLuz+ "</font></font>");
```

Error Completo:

```
C:\Users\HELENC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_modified_sketch_36054\sketch_aug11a.ino: In function 'void loop()':

sketch_aug11a:86: error: invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [15]' to binary 'operator+'

              String cadena = ("<font color='red'> <font size=5>" +sensorLuz+ "</font></font>");   

                                                                              ^

exit status 1
invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [15]' to binary 'operator+'
```

En resumen dice que es un operador invalido y necesito unir las 2 variables

Comment: Leete esta pregunta similar, que aunque es c++, es el lenguaje en el que se basó arduino

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23936246/error-invalid-operands-of-types-const-char-35-and-const-char-2-to-binar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema lo tenés porque sumás objetos de clases distintas.
Casteá el int a clase String al incluirlo en la operación.
Quedaría así

```
    int sensorLuz = analogRead(pinSensorLuz);
    String cadena = ("<font color='red'> <font size=5>" + (String)sensorLuz+ "</font></font>");
```